# Tag dependencies to ignore questions

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

It would be useful to have dependencies among tags for a **better selection of ignored questions**.

For example, I would expect that if I choose to ignore the tag *fortran*, then I will automatically ignore any question containing the tag *fortran95* (even if the basic tag *fortran* is missing from the question). The same should happen e.g. for *c++11* when ignoring *c++*.

Is it possible to set such dependencies among tags so that questions are ignored based on "parent" tags ?

This feature of course needs a **tag hierarchy**, with parent-children relations. To make another example: *Java8* and *Java9* would be both children of *Java*. Therefore, if I ignore *Java*, then I would automatically ignore both *Java8* and *Java9*. If I just ignore *Java9*, then *Java8* wouldn't be ignored (because it is at the same level of the hierachy).

Comment: But what if I want to ignore Java9 but not Java8?

Comment: We need hierarchy. For example, Java8 and Java9 are both children of Java. Therefore, if you ignore Java, then you ignore both. If you ignore Java9 you don't ignore Java8.... I've updated the question.

Comment: Who decides what the hierarchy will look like? Some would argue that Java9 should be child of Java8.

Comment: I see. Then, we could have such mechanism only for very general tags (e.g., C++, Java, Fortran)...